# In Church History, when and how did The Glory Be (The Doxology) originate?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, prayer, the-glory-be

In Church History, when and how did [The Glory Be](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/46446/which-is-the-correct-renedring-in-english-of-the-glory-be-the-doxology) (The Doxology) originate?

Is the history of this prayer known as to when and how it originated?

The Glory Be is part of those basic prayers like the Our Father and [the Hail Mary](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/995/what-exactly-is-a-hail-mary).

---

Related question: [How are doxologies formed for common prayers?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/how-are-doxologies-formed-for-common-prayers)

Answer (score 3):

According to the Catholic Encyclopedia article for the [Doxology](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05150a.htm), it was used at least as early as the fourth century "as a protest against Arian subordination.

The article goes on to say that in the West, the Latin version was put into a canonical form at the Fourth Synod of Toledo in 633.